# Chromium Updated for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: chromium

I haven't received an update notice for Chromium browser lately.  My version is 97.0.4692 and what little info I could find says there is a version 98.0.4758.81. Should I find a way to update to most recent version or stick with the repo version?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See last week's Desktop Team updates: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/desktop-team-updates-monday-7th-february-2022/26465/10. The Snap has been updated to 98. I have not seen work yet on the deb.

Comment: Thanks - I haven't been using snap packages so I will wait and see about the .deb package